# How to stop keyboard from scrolling up tableview

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, keyboard, hide

Weird question.

In my fist view controller, i am able to move my textfields up when the keyboard first appears and back to its original position when I tap on the return key.

Now on my second view controller, where I haven't set code for any of the textfields to move, they still do.  Funny thing is the first textfield is never even moved in the first view controller.  Not sure why or how to stop this.

Any clues?

Comment: Is your textfields in a tableview cell?

Comment: Yes, the textfield is in a Table View Cell